# How to choose random N item from an array in Javascript without repetition?

Tags: javascript, random

I have an array containing some items, let's say numbers:

```
[23,4,67,8,29,46,7,2,98]
```

How it is possibile to choose N different random number (no more, no less) from the array?

Behaviour expected: if N=3

```
[4,23,98] accepted
[7,67,29] accepted
[7,67,7]  not accepted
```

**EDIT**: Finally I've found a pretty good **solution**. The thread as been closed so I'm publishing my solution here just for people passing by.
I had an array long M and N numbers to choose so I made an array containing M numbers (indexesArray) applied the Fisher Yates algorithm to shuffle number corresponding this way to indexes of my initial array and took the first M items from that. Thanks to @ArneHugo for pointing the right path to follow.

```
var arrayContainingNumbersToChoose=[23,4,67,8,29,46,7,2,98];
var indexesArray=[];
var N=5;
var resultArray=[];

var M=arrayContainingNumbersToChoose.length;

for (let i = 0; i < M; i++) {
   indexesArray.push(i);
} // result like [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

indexesArray=fisherYatesShuffle(indexesArray); // result like [2, 4, 7, 6, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5]

for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
resultArray.push(arrayContainingNumbersToChoose[indexesArray[i]]);
}

console.log(resultArray);

function fisherYatesShuffle(a) {
      var j, x, i;
      for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          x = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = x;
      }
      return a;
  }
```

Comment: Is performance important? Can you mutate the array?

Comment: Performance is important, i can mutate the array

Comment: this looks a bit like a "do my homework"-question. Also, could you let us know if you tried anything?

Comment: Hi! This issue has been [repeatedly asked and answered](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+random+array+without+repeat). Please search before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Sorry, I swear I tried searching but each answer had different problems. I tried choosing indexes of the array as random number excluding already chosen but this could be bad performant, taking a lot more step this issue could require.

Comment: @SashaGrievus Mods on SO are very aggressively blocking a thread by marking them as duplicates. Sometimes this happens so fast that I doubt they could have read the original well, or the duplicate answer. While I understand the need to avoid duplicates, this marking happens too fast.

Comment: @ArneHugo By mutate you are implying I could shuffle the array and taking the first N element maybe? This could be a good performant way to approach the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var arr = [23,4,67,8,29,46,7,2,98];
var result = [];
var map = {};
var n = 3;
var i = arr.length;
var counter = arr.length+n;
while(result.length != n){
      num = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)];
      if(!map[num]){
        map[num] = i;
        result.push(num);
      }
      if(counter <= 0) // stop finding random numbers if counter is zero.
        break;
      counter--;
      i--;
      if(i  == 0)
        i = arr.length;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: cool, but that while couldn't go on forever if you're very very very unlucky? Performance was a problem I was trying to deal with

Comment: @SashaGrievus i have updated the answer, i have limited the while loop. it will not run infinitely now.

Comment: thank you very much. But let's say that at some point num keeps being only numbers already chosen, this could go forever anyway, couldn't? I understand that this case is at limit and absurd, but still means that if a big number of 'already chosen num' is generated, this could require a lot more step than required causing bad performance, i guess

Comment: @SashaGrievus The while loop wont go forever as we decrement counter in each iteration. So when the counter becomes zero,  we break the loop.

Comment: Umh, this is being executed max 'counter' times that in this case is array.lenght+n=9+3=12. Having 12 possibilities to generate the number, if random numbers are to be discarded 10 times this couldn't result in having only 2 items in variable 'result'? Unlikely, but could?

Comment: @SashaGrievus yes correct, to prevent that you can splice that element from array, only when  the element is repeated.